# get rid of padding in cells (set image to size of cell)

Tags: ios

[image: image of table cells]

I have a table that presents images, the image is pinned to all four sides of the cell. The cell is of height 200, But there seems to be black paddings inside the cell for each image. I don't know where the padding is coming from since I figured if I pin the image to the cell it shouldn't have any padding?

Note: I subclass UITableViewCell so "self" is the cell itself

```
[self.thumbnail autoPinEdge:ALEdgeRight toEdge:ALEdgeRight ofView:self];
[self.thumbnail autoPinEdge:ALEdgeLeft toEdge:ALEdgeLeft ofView:self];
[self.thumbnail autoPinEdge:ALEdgeTop toEdge:ALEdgeTop ofView:self];
[self.thumbnail autoPinEdge:ALEdgeBottom toEdge:ALEdgeBottom ofView:self];
[self.thumbnail autoSetDimension:ALDimensionHeight toSize:200];
```

And then inside the UITableController I have

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  return 200;
}
```

Comment: it seems like your images are set to Aspect to Fit, try to change them to Scale To Fill or Aspect to Fill

Comment: Agree with the above comment. The issue is not the size of the view but the size of its content. If you set the content mode to fill, it will zoom to remove those black bars. The sides of your image will be a little cut off though.

Comment: mmmhmm yep got it used Aspect to Fill, thanks for the help, I'll mark it as the right answer